# Stop react causing an infinite loop using useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, infinite-loop

I am very new to react and node, I have managed to create an API for a simple todo list. I have fetched the data from the api and presenting it on the screen.

If I leave the dependency array empty on the `useEffect()` hook it will only render once and doesn't loop. But If I add a new Todo it will not update the list unless I refresh. So I put the todos state into the dependency array, this will then show the new item when I add it but if I look at the network tab in the dev tools its hitting the api in an infinite loop. What am I doing wrong ?

here is the code:

*App*

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Todo from "./components/Todo";
import Heading from "./components/Heading";
import NewTodoForm from "./components/NewTodoForm";

const App = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getTodos = async () => {
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/todos");
      const data = await res.json();
      setTodos(data);
    };

    getTodos();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Heading todos={todos} />
      <section className="todos-container">
        <ul className="todos">
          {todos.map((todo) => (
            <Todo key={todo._id} todo={todo} />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </section>
      <section className="todo-form">
        <NewTodoForm />
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

*Heading*

```
import React from "react";

const Heading = ({ todos }) => (
  <header>
    <h1>Todos</h1>
    <p>
      {todos.length} {todos.length === 1 ? "Item" : "Items"}
    </p>
  </header>
);

export default Heading;
```

*Todo*

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Todo = ({ todo }) => (
  <li>
    {todo.name}
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </li>
);

export default Todo;
```

*NewTodoForm*

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Plus } from "react-feather";

const NewTodoForm = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: "",
    completed: false,
  });

  const { name } = formData;

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    await fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/todos", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    });

    setFormData({
      name: "",
      completed: false,
    });
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="form-control">
        <Plus className="plus" />
        <input
          name="name"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Add New Item"
          onChange={handleOnChange}
          value={name}
        />
        <button>Add</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default NewTodoForm;
```

If I comment all the components out and only have the App component it still infinite loops when I add todos to the dependency array of the `useEffect()` hook.

Comment: It will run into infinite loop because you are setting todo inside useEffect and giving the same as dependency

Comment: move this getTodos to outside of your useEffect

Comment: when you add a new todo its not good to fetch all the todos, you just need to fetch the newly created todo only so you might need to change the way you thinking, either you can get saved todo as a return from savetodo function and add that to the existing todos state or else fetch the only todo that you need as a seperate request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So instead of giving that as a dependency write the function outside the `useEffect` so that you can call that function after you add a todo

Example:

```
  const getTodos = async () => {
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/todos");
      const data = await res.json();
      setTodos(data);
    };

 useEffect(() => {
    getTodos();
  }, []);
```

So `getTodos` will only run once initially and runs again only on the `onSubmit` or `onClick` of your `Todo`, So, just call  `getTodos` function onSubmit or onClick